# C:\Python\python.exe: can't open file '<unprintable file name>': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm trying to open Python project through bat file and getting error in cmd(win10):

`C:\Python\python.exe: can't open file '<unprintable file name>': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

My bat file contained:

```
py -3 %~dp0\data_analyzer.py %*
```

Also tried with:

```
py -3 %cd%\data_analyzer.py %*
```

I've found that `<unprintable file name>` is something with encoding. But encoding of what? Where is that issue? I've checked differet .py files and also have same issue. 
If it's in that bat file I've tried to change encoing in Notepad, but it doesn't change anything. What else I can do and where to look for answer?

Comment: Thx. One step closer. Now only showing "C:\Python\python.exe: can't open file '\data_analyzer.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". But it's same folder.

Comment: Try inserting double quotes around the path e.g. `py -3 "%~dp0\data_analyzer.py" %*`.

Comment: Yes. It's working.Thx. You're great.